# Deciding content of html tag based on a conditional in mvc3 asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

This sounds really basic yet I couldn't find the answer.

I pass a Message struct to the View and I want to display it.

If the Message.Category field is "Technical" I want to display "Technical Problem" else just display it as it is.

How do I make the view understand that Technical Problem isn't a statement but html text I want to display?

My code:

```
<span class="cright" id="cat">
@{
    if (String.Compare(ViewBag.Message.Category, "Technical") == 0) 
    {
     Technical Problem <----THIS  
    } 
    else @ViewBag.Message.Category
 }
</span>
```

More info:
I'm working on a messaging system. Users create a message and as it is being sent they can view it. The category is compulsory (Question, Suggestion or Technical Problem) and to avoid redundancy in the database I truncate the last option to just 'Technical', however when the users view their sent message I want it to show up in full.

Thanks everyone; from all your answers I arrived at:

```
<span class="cright" id="cat">

      @if (ViewBag.Message.Category == "Technical ")
         {<text>Technical Problem</text>}
       else
         {<text>@ViewBag.Message.Category</text>}

</span>
```

which works just as I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Original Answer**

```
if(ViewBag.Message.Category == "Technical")
{
  <span>Technical problem</span>
}
else
{
  <span>Problem is : @(ViewBag.Message.Category)</span>
}
```

**Updated Answer**

```
  //Model
   public class Message
   {
      public int ID {get; set;}
      public string Message {get; set;}
      public string Category {get; set;}
   }

   //Controller
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      //If you use Linq to Sql, I made this up but this should give you an idea

      using(MessageDataContext context = new MessageDataContext())
      {
        var messages = context.Messages.Where(m => m.Category == "Technical")
       .Select(m => new Message { ID = m.ID, Message = m.Text, Category = m.Category});

        return View(messages);
      }
    }

//View
@model IEnumerable<Message>

@foreach(var message in Model)
{
    if(message.Category == "Technical")
    {
      //Id and class will be "TechnicalMessage1"
      //Now you can create css class called "TechnicalMessage1" and only message with Id = 1 will have it
      <span id="@(message.Category)Message@(message.ID)" class="@(message.Category)Message@(message.ID)">Technical problem</span>
    }
    else
    {
      <span>Problem is : @(ViewBag.Message.Category)</span>
    }
}
```

Comment: ! Thank you. This syntax worked. 
The only problem I have with this is that the span has a class and id which is the same regardless of the content. Is there really no way to make this conditional work WITHIN an already created tag?

Comment: @Nieszka Yes there is but you will need to pass somekind of id for your message, best would be to create a class which would hold int Id and string message, I will update answer.

Comment: @Nieszka Did you mean something like this?

Comment: Thank you! 
I'm not actually pulling these messages from the database, (although I probably should). What happens is the user gets a chance to view the message he just sent and that is only passed between the two views in a viewbag, only admins can view the sent messages and I think adding the extra characters over there is not worth the extra computation, they'll know the distinction.
But thank you so much for your answer! I'd vote up if I hadn't just joined and lacked the reputation to do so!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
@("Technical Problem")
```

alternatively

```
<text>Technical Problem</text>
```

alternatively

```
@:Technical Problem
```

Read http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx for the syntax ..

Comment: Hey, trying your suggestions:
the first one doesn't seem to work but it's not higlighted by VS so I'm guessing it's a problem elsewhere in the code (?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<text>Technical Problem</text>
```

for this.